# Implementation of doubly linked list

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None

class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.count = 0

    def insertStart(self, data):
        nn = Node(data)
        self.count +=1
        if(self.head==None):
            self.head = nn
            self.tail = nn
            return
        nn.next = self.head
        self.head.prev = nn
        self.head = nn

    def insertEnd(self, data):
        nn = Node(data)
        self.count +=1
        if(self.tail is None):
            self.head = nn
            self.tail = nn
            return

        nn.prev = self.tail
        self.tail.next = nn
        self.tail = nn

    def insertAtPos(self, data, pos):
        nn = Node(data)
        if(self.count < pos):
            return -1

        mid = int(self.count/2)
        # print(mid)

        if(pos<=mid):
            temp = self.head
            for i in range(1, pos-1):
                temp = temp.next

            nn.next = temp.next
            nn.prev = temp
            temp.next = nn
        else:
            temp = self.tail
            for i in range(self.count-1, pos, -1):
                temp = temp.prev

            print(temp.data)
            nn.prev = temp.prev
            nn.next = temp
            temp.prev = nn

        self.count += 1



    def removeStart(self):
        self.count -=1
        if(self.head is None):
            return -1

        if(self.count == 1):
            self.head = None
            self.tail = None

        self.head = self.head.next
        self.head.prev = None

    def removeEnd(self):
        self.count -=1
        if(self.tail is None):
            return -1

        self.tail = self.tail.prev
        self.tail.next = None


    def display(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp is not None):
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next


    dd = DoublyLinkedList()

    dd.insertEnd(40)
    dd.insertStart(22)
    dd.insertEnd(42)
    dd.insertStart(20)
    dd.insertStart(23)
    # dd.display()
    print()
    dd.removeStart()
    dd.removeEnd()
    dd.display()
    print()
    dd.insertAtPos(33, 3)
    dd.display()
```

In the `insertAtPos` function, my `else` part is not inserting the new node, everything seems to work fine but when I use display function new node that is added is not appearing. There's some problem in the `else` part. Please help!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems that something went not quite right with the formatting of your code in the post. Can you have a second look at that? Also the init() functions should have double underscores. Seems to be a slip of the pen too, but you may want to correct that as well in the post.

Comment: Hello sir, init function has double underscores already. I don't think that's the problem because all the other the functions seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In else part, you forgot to add :

```py
temp.prev.next = nn
```

And change `for loop` in `else` part to:

```py
for i in range(self.count, pos, -1):
```

Comment: Hey Sai, I noticed I was missing that part, thanku so much for the help. But even after adding that code is not working as it should.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I was mistaking and adding temp.prev.next = nn  after adding temp.prev = nn.

Comment: hey @HimanjliJain, there is one more problem in your code. I have noticed it right now. I will say it, just try to fix it or if you want i can help you. The error is whenever you give ```1``` as parameter to ```insertAtPos```, It won't work correctly because we also need to change ```self.head```